# Nginx add www and remove trailing slashes

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to rewrite my example.com to www.example.com and also make my urls www.example.com/contact_us/ to www.example.com/contact_us and can't seem to get the configuration correct.  Does anyone have this working in nginx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this regex will strip any trailing slash.  You may not need the ? inside the parentheses.

EDIT: Redirect to www.example.com and strip trailing slash in both servers

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite ^(.+?)/?$ http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
  server_name www.example.com;

  rewrite ^(.+)/$ http://www.example.com$1 permanent;

  ... handle everything that doesn't end in a / ...
}
```

Comment: Here is what I have tried but gives me a 404 and won't even hit my rails app now.

server {
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite ^/(.+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
server {
  server_name *.example.com;
  rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

Comment: Ah, I didn't think this through.  I was just stripping the trailing / from the force-www redirect.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok weird thing is that this actually appears to be creating the proper urls, but I'm using Engine Yard and I'm getting a 404 which I can't seem to figure out.  It is only when I add the 2 server requests which my server_names are example.com *.example.com

Comment: thanks again for your help.  I had to do if statements because I couldn't figure out how to get these server blocks working.  I'm using 0.8.x version of Nginx so maybe that is part of the issue (not sure) but the if's worked great(although they aren't the best practice).  not sure why these wouldn't work, but the rewrites did.